# Mallet CRF Sequence Classification Training Data Format

Tags: java, nlp, mallet, crf

I am trying to train a CRF sequence model using the Mallet library but I am missing some important information.  I found a an example in the library itself at https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/examples/TrainCRF.java
however the example does not state the format of the input training data so I do not know how to recreate it.

Mallet does have a data import example at http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import-devel.php but the particular example seems to be for document classification and not CRF sequence models which is my use case.

I tried putting the input training data in the form used at http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/sequences.php i.e.

```
Bill CAPITALIZED noun
slept non-noun
here LOWERCASE STOPWORD non-noun
```

and test data in the form

```
CAPITAL Al
        slept
        here
```

however based on the output logs it does not seem to be the correct format.  For example one line in the log is `INFO: testing label slept P � R 0 F1 �` but `slept` is not a label - the labels should be `noun` or `non-noun`.

So if someone could tell me what format the training data should be in that would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that while running the tests you did not have the `--train true` flag?

Comment: @iamwhoiam I'm not running it via command line.  I'm using the code example that I referenced

Comment: The code sample you link to has the line that refers to the `training` file commented out. Is it possible your code is trying to train on the test file? that would cause `slept` to look like a label, since it's at the end of the line...

Comment: @polm23 Ah I think you are right - of course the test data has to be in the same format as the training data - Not sure what I was thinking :) If you want to add that as an answer I would be happy to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sample you link to has [the line that refers to the training file](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/d7cbd220f5fc21c232d2a89bbb5a1e036747abaf/src/cc/mallet/examples/TrainCRF.java#L61) commented out. Is it possible your code is trying to train on the test file? That would cause `slept` to look like a label since it's at the end of the line, and would explain the error.

For the record, I tried the example using the test data you gave above (using the command line, not the code sample) and it worked, so the test/train format seems to be OK.